# Prevent alphanumeric strings containing an 'E' from being treated as numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I work with CSV files that have around 3000 lines, and one column uses the format `0dddddddHH`, `d` being a decimal and `H` an hexadecimal.

That means most of the data looks like `0128522FB` but some of them look like `01283227E2`. That's very problematic because it's automatically parsed as scientific notation, it gets displayed as `1.28E+08`. The worst thing is that I can't even change the format back to text, because the original string has already been changed to `128322700`.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour so that I don't completely break files and lose information?

According to [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8), it can be disabled for dates but with numbers with `E`, I have to add a `'`. That's not doable in my case, and especially not doable in Excel because the information has already been modified.

(I'm using the 2013 business suite)

Comment: How do you bring the CSV file to Excel? If you are opening it as a text file, you will be given the option to specify the data type for each column. In that case, you could set the data type for that column to text before importing the data. Note that if you double-click a CSV file, it will open in Excel without the Text Import Wizard; however, if you press Ctrl+O in Excel to choose the same CSV file, you will get the Text Import Wizard.

Comment: This ^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @Mikko I used to open them by double clicking. I tried with ctrl+O and I didn't get a wizard. Does the file have to be a .txt for it to work?

Comment: You can also rename the file to txt to trick Excel. I just took a random CSV and checked the behavior with double-clicking and Ctrl+Oing.

Comment: @DavidPostill: ^^^^^^^^^^?

Comment: I don't know how it is in Excel 2013, but in the current version there's this button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0iDa.png I'm sure the feature exists in 2013, but the button probably has a different name and might be in a different place.

Comment: Arrows pointing to your comment, as in pay attention to it ...

Comment: @Giffyguy: Excel 2013 view, Data tab open in ribbon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGrd9.png, so there one would click From Text (third button from the left).

Comment: @Mikko Yes, or `From Other Sources`. There are multiple ways to get the desired result.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat,, I  can suggest you VBA macro to put apostrophe before each number in column to convert into Text ,, please confirm through comments,, also [Edit] your post & add new TAG `VBA`.

Comment: @RajeshS As I said in my question, once I opened the csv in Excel it's too late to add `'`s, the info has already been modified (`01283227E2` has been changed to `128322700`, no quote can revert that). Also, the csv is used by other programs and I'd have to remove the quotes afterwards for it to be usable.

Comment: @Mikko Could you write an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat,, you may apply the VBA macro after few of the rows getting as E or in Scientific notation,, the VBA macro with put Apostrophe as Prefix to convert into Text !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing Giffyguy's input on the button on the ribbon, you can click From Text on the Data tab of the ribbon (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGrd9.png) to open the CSV file as a text file, then explictly specify text data type for the column containing hexadecimal data in the Text Import Wizard.

Double-clicking the file in Explorer will not work because this will skip the Text Import Wizard.